# Unable to turn off syntax highlighting with lua script in neovim

Tags: lua

running newvim 0.6.1. Totally clean install, no plugins.

In `init.lua`:

`vim.opt.syntax` = "off"

Also tried "false" and "disabled." Didn't work. Also tried `vim.g`, `vim.o`, `vim.bo`. Didn't work.

Syntax highlighting still shows up.

In `init.vim`:

`syntax off`

No syntax highlighting.

Answer (score 1):

Setting `&syntax`, as well as `&filetype` option, in vimrc / init.vim / init.lua is pretty much meaningless.

If you don't need the syntax then do `:syntax off` (or `:syntax manual`). Maybe also `:filetype off` if really wanted.

Answer (score 1):

In your lua config:

```lua
vim.cmd("syntax off")
```

Reference: https://neovim.io/doc/user/lua.html#vim.cmd()